# SPFX from scratch

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I would like to know if it is possible to implement an SP application **WITHOUT** using yeoman.

Let me explain: I would like to create an application using VueJS and WebPack (maybe without gulp and Typescript), change the Typescript version used, customizing files as I like.

I have seen that it is possible to integrate VueJs into a solution, and I have also seen that it is possible to add configurations to WebPack, but I am a type that likes to understand what is underneath and have the TOTAL control on the application, I do not like very much the tools that do everything.

Does anyone know if it is possible to create an SPFX application **from scratch**? Is there a tutorial?

Comment: did you already found a tutorial for this?

Comment: No. No tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be possible. After all, what you need is a .zip file with a number of JavaScript and JSON files. The problem is, that you would have to exactly mimic what the standard build toolchain generates when building and packaging the project. If one thing would be off, your solution wouldn't work and I suspect it wouldn't be easy for you to find out what's wrong exactly. I haven't heard of any initiatives that replace the standard build toolchain provided by Microsoft.